# can i configure 2 (XBee series 2) modules using one explorer

Tags: xbee

Can I configure 2 XBEE modules one then another using 1 XBEE Explorer, or I MUST do this configuration operation for them at the same time and I need 2 Explorer modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one. 
In order to communicate in Point To Point, you must configure each xbee to belong to the same NetworkID (PAN ID). XBees can only communicate with each other if they have the same network ID. Configure one, switch the xbee then configure the other ([see here](https://learn.adafruit.com/xbee-radios/point2point))

There are more advanced configurations that you can use ([check this tutorial for extended information](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/exploring-xbees-and-xctu)).

Comment: thank you, it's the same if i'll do star or mesh right?.                  I have another question can I send information from 2 sources to one destination .. or xbee is only for broadcasting?

Comment: I've never tested it, but yes it is possible according to manual in multicast([see page 74 example 4](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90002002.pdf)). Just remember that star must have only one coordinator. take a look here also: http://jeffbelback.me/projects/2014/09/17/XbeeDeviceTypes/

Comment: thanks again.  I have another new question, I was test the communicating of the 2 XBEEs series 2, and I connected one to the computer and the other to the arduino... but while running a code to send hello world msg from arduino, it doesn't appear in the XBee XTC console.. what should I do?

Comment: You don't see anything? Have you set the same PAN ID right? Correct baudrates also?